# How to recover from "RuntimeError: Session is closed"

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-asyncio, aiodocker

I'm using `aiodocker` to monitor Docker events and Containers (among other things, but those are troubling me).

Sometimes (only every couple of days) the connection to the docker-socket gets lost and calling e.g. `client.containers.list()` gives me:

```
>>> client = Docker()
>>> containers = await client.containers.list(all=True)
   File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiodocker/containers.py", line 23, in list                                                                                                                                                                   
     data = await self.docker._query_json(                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiodocker/docker.py", line 300, in _query_json                                                                                                                                                               
     async with self._query(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiodocker/utils.py", line 309, in __aenter__                                                                                                                                                                 
     resp = await self._coro                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiodocker/docker.py", line 248, in _do_query                                                                                                                                                                 
     response = await self.session.request(                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 426, in _request                                                                                                                                                                    
     raise RuntimeError("Session is closed")                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 RuntimeError: Session is closed
```

Meanwhile ongoing asynchronous calls to `DockerContainer.stats()` magically explode after a couple of seconds, printing on the log:

```
ERROR    │ asyncio    │ Task exception was never retrieved                      
future: <Task finished name='Task-43' coro=<<async_generator_athrow
without __name__>()> exception=RuntimeError('aclose(): asynchronous generator is already running')>                                        
RuntimeError: aclose(): asynchronous generator is already running
```

It would be an option of course to just give up, terminate gracefully and re-start the application. But this would be bad for me, as I want to keep track of Docker events and container stats. So I want to keep the application running, if possible.

But unfortunately I didn't find any `reconnect`-semantic inside `aiodocker`, except `client.connector.connect()`, which doesn't help much (as it's not being called by `Docker.__init__()` anyway).

My next approach was to wrap *every* command involving the `Docker` instance, catch the error (which sometime is a `RuntimeError` and sometimes a `DockerError`), replace the `Docker` instance with a new one (to have a connected session again) and re-run the command.

But this is a very cumbersome approach because some `aiodocker` commands use injected references to the old `Docker` instance. E.g. `container.show()` internally calls `data = await self.docker._query_json(...)`, i.E. I would have to replace every reference to the old `Docker` instance with the new one. (and stop async calls before)

So I keep hoping: is there some way to react on a session-disconnect and re-connect the instance rather than hot-exchanging all `Docker` instances and asynchronous calls?